# Swift: Using NSDataDetectors

Tags: swift

I'm trying to port some Obj-c code and having some trouble creating a NSDataDetector.

In Objective-C I would do this:

```
NSDataDetector *linkDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
```

From the documentation I should be able to do this:

```
let linkDetector = NSDataDetector.dataDetectorWithTypes(NSTextCheckingType.Link, error: &error)
```

But I get a compiler error: *'NSTextCheckingType' is not convertible to 'NStextCheckingTypes'*

If try this:

```
let linkDetector = NSDataDetector.dataDetectorWithTypes(NSTextCheckingTypes(), error: &gError)
```

It passes however, I get a runtime exception:

```
[NSDataDetector initWithTypes:error:]: no data detector types specified'
```

Not sure if it's a bug or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`NSTextCheckingTypes` is typealiased to UInt64; use the `rawValue` property on an `NSTextCheckingType` to convert it.

```
let ld = NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingType.Link.rawValue, error: nil)
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you! I guess I'm going to have dig harder through Obj-c APIs harder when trying to debug issues like these. Thanks again.

Comment: FYI: this API has changed and is now .toRaw() (see davextreme's answer)

Comment: FYI: toRaw() is now rawValue. see Max MacLeod's answer

Answer (score 9):

davextreme's solution returns an error in Xcode 6.1 (6A1046a).

> Method 'fromRaw' has been replaced with a property 'rawValue'

New syntax uses `rawValue` instead of `toRaw()` as follows:

```
let ld = NSDataDetector(types:NSTextCheckingType.Link.rawValue, error: nil)
```

Comment: this the the correct and most updated answer as of Xcode 6.1.2 beta 3

Answer (score 6):

jatoben's solution returns an error in beta 4:

> 'NSTextCheckingType' does not have a member named value

Changing it to `toRaw()` resolves this:

```
let ld = NSDataDetector.dataDetectorWithTypes(NSTextCheckingType.Link.toRaw(), error: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Working solution for Swift 4:**

```
let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
```

*Reference link to Apple Docs:*
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstextcheckingresult.checkingtype/1411725-link

Comment: `let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
if let _detect = detector {...... }`

Answer (score 0):

As of Swift 5.7 you can do the following:

```
import RegexBuilder

let input =
"""
...
(Stackowerflow)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24345928/swift-using-nsdatadetectors
---
"""

let url = Reference(URL.self)
let regex = Regex {
    Capture(.url(), as: url)
}

if let result = input.firstMatch(of: regex) {
    print("URL: \(result[url])")
}
```